# Connecting to MSSQL server 2008 with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, wamp

We are using MSSQL server 2008 on Win server 2008 R2 and have installed `Apache (2.2.19)` and `PHP (5.2.17)` separately. We have installd the MSSQL module for PHP and usingthe following connection string:

```
$myc = mssql_connect(Server, SiteDatabaseUsername, SiteDatabasePassword) or die('Can\'t connect to mssql Database Server: '.mssql_get_last_message($myc));
$db = mssql_select_db(SiteDatabaseName, $myc) or die('Can\'t find database: '.mssql_get_last_message($myc));
```

But it gives us this error:

```
Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server: localhost\MSSQLSERVER in D:\Apache2.2\htdocs\adminarea\_core.php on line 89
Can't connect to mssql Database Server:
```

We have used the `IP:PORT`, `localhost\MSSQLSERVER` and `COMPUTERNAME\MSSQLSERVER` but don't seem to be getting anywhere, can anyone help please?

Comment: Have you tried installing the newer SQLSRV drivers from Microsoft, since MSSQL is no longer supported? Also, does `phpinfo()` confirm the availability of the driver to PHP?

Comment: Try looking at the ntwdblib.dll - see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/470036/327074

Comment: Actually it looks like this question is just a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469964/unable-to-connect-to-mssql-database-via-php

Answer (score 1):

A few things come to mind:

1)  Make sure you have the sqlsrv driver package from MS, and make sure you're loading it properly in php.ini (use phpinfo() to verify).

2)  If this was a vanilla installation of SQL Server, its likely that only windows authentication is turned on.  Open the SQL Enterprise Manager and make sure you have SQL Server Authentication enabled on your database.

3)  Make sure that you have enabled network access to SQL Server.  I'm not immediately certain whether the new MS drivers use named pipes to communicate with the server, or if they expect that the server will be accessed via the network.

These are the issues I routinely encounter when getting PHP speaking to a new MSSQL server.