# PHP mssql_connect() on Windows Server 2012

Tags: php, sql-server

We just have a transfer from old Windows Server, to the new Windows Server 2012.

After that transfer new XAMPP was installed, and I recognized, that mssql_connect was discountinued some time ago. So I checked that last version when it was supported was 5.2.
So I reinstalled XAMPP for older one but I still can't make it work.

I am getting error:

```
 Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server: SERVER/SQLEXPRESS in F:\xampp_php5.2\htdocs\open_db.php on line 2
Error!
```

My file looks like this:

```
<?php
$link = mssql_connect("SERVER/SQLEXPRESS","login", "pass") or die("Error!");
mssql_select_db("dbinet") or die("DB not exist");           

echo 'success';
?>
```

I can login to this server (SERVER/SQLEXPRESS) using login and pass directly by SQL Server Managment Studio, but can't by webpage...

Any idea where is a problem?

Comment: So what is in the error message?

Comment: Could you replace bla bla bla with the _actual_ error message?

Comment: here you go, but there is not much information over there...

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469964/unable-to-connect-to-mssql-database-via-php

Comment: No. I forgot to mention that I was trying to find solution earlier, and I already copied the ntwdblib.dll (2000.80.2039.0)